# Several design issues between SU main & meta

Tags: bug, design

I stumbled upon some minor layout issues while switching superuser's main and meta. I felt only one of them wasn't enough for a meta post, so I collected them.

#### Fixed over time

- <strike>The superuser website header and meta.superuser header aren't exactly at the same position. Please note, that stackoverflow's [main](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) header are well aligned</strike>  » Fixed
- <strike>Community Bulletin link title is also slightly at another position as its counterpart on the main site</strike> » Fixed
- <strike>The `r` in superuser gets cut off for some reason on the main site header</strike>  » Fixed

  - <strike>Missing space on `Profile » activity » suggestions` between the word *on* and the *subject*</strike>
- <strike>Column headers are missing on SU footer while present on meta.SU footer</strike>
- <strike>In the meta.SU footer. Those two links are underlined while they aren't on SU main site footer</strike>

#### Edit:

<sup>After two years, the following things probably will never change.</sup>

- The <strike>about</strike> *Tour* link is missing on meta SU footer while it is [present on the main](https://superuser.com/about) site's footer
- The tag filter field, only visible while reviewing, doesn't allow tags with placeholders like `*excel*`. But placeholders are allowed when using the main site's favorite/ignored tag option
  [image]

/thx & closed :)

Comment: The **r** in the superuser logo is also cut off in Chrome :( It seems like `sprites.png` is cut off.

Comment: There is no `about` for meta.su.  Not sure about other sites, but IMO it's not needed for any of the metas.

Comment: Since meta.stackoverflow has this link, I thought its worth to note

Comment: 2/6 fixed. Will the rest remain as it currently is?

Comment: Meta.stackoverflow.com is a special case, so the "about" link there is needed. There is no such link on any of the other Stack Exchange Meta sites.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's been several redesigns since and the problem is no longer reproducible

Answer (score -3):

As children of the StackOverflow system, I expect sites to have some minor differences from their parent.

The concept of there being a (fuzzy) continuity between the site is a concept that I agree with.  But, to expect that each site will be a cookie-cutter variant of every neighbor isn't something I would expect.

Some gross differences between sites maybe deserve some notice and intervention, but in general, I think that SuperUser fits the template pretty well.

For SU and meta-SU to have some minor differences, I consider trivial.

*(all of this is my opinion)